# Plotting data with ListPlot where the coloration of the data depends on its position in an array?

Tags: plotting

Imagine I have some data in a list I'd like to plot using `ListPlot` in *Mathematica 9*, for example:

```
ListPlot[Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 1, 10^3}]]
```

How can I specify that the data points should be colored according to a linearly scaling interval from one `RGB` value to another (e.g. `Red --> Blue, Green --> Red`, etc.) depending on the point's index in the array?  Can we do something similar using `ListPointPlot3D`?

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{i, Cos[i], Sin[i]}, {i, 1, 10^3}]]
```

Comment: Have you looked at [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html)?

Comment: @Ali Yes, but I couldn't see how to make it work with the index of the datapoints instead of their values?

Comment: How is this: ListPointPlot3D[Table[{i, Cos[i], Sin[i]}, {i, 1, 10^3}], ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[x]]]

Comment: `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` will pass the unscaled x coordinate of the point to the colour function (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 1, 10^3}], 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["NeonColors"][x]]]
```

[image]

You might want to choose a less garish color set.